# How to get Recently View Product For Guest User In Magento

Tags: magento

I am Facing one problem when i want to display recent products for guest user, is there any ways to show recently view product for guest user,

Magento support Recently View Product For Registered User But for Guest User How to show Recently view products by that particular Guest...

I am waiting for your kind response,

Hope i get some reply on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can do it changing the core files...have you tried that way ??

Comment: Yes. I also need this functionality.

Comment: oh thank for your kind response i did it but magento not support recently view product for guest user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is phtml

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()):
$ids = '';
foreach ($_products as $_item) {
    $ids .= $_item->getId() . ';';
}
?>
<div class="lftHeading">
<span
        style="text-transform:capitalize;background:url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/clo_left_heading_bullet2.gif') ?>) top left no-repeat;"
        >recently viewed</span>
</div>
<div class="innerRgtMenu recently_viewed_block">
<table id="recently-viewed-items">
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_products as $_item): if ($i == 3) {
    continue;
} ?>
    <?php $product = $_item ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a style="border:1px solid #DDDDDD;float:left;margin:5px;padding:5px;"
               href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item, array('_nosid' => true)) ?>" class="product-image"><img
                src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>"
                width="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"/></a></td>
        <td><a style="position:relative;top:3px;font-size:11px;"
               href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item, array('_nosid' => true)) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <?php $i++;
endforeach; ?>
</table>
<div style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 2px; text-align: center; width: 140px;">
    <input type="button" class="button recently_viewed_btn" value="<?php echo $this->__('Email These To Me') ?> "
           onClick="email_recently('<?php echo $ids; ?>')"/>
</div>
<div style="margin:5px;">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>recently-viewed-items/"><?php echo $this->__('See All Recently Viewed') ?></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
```

and php file

```
class Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract
{
const XML_PATH_RECENTLY_VIEWED_COUNT    = 'catalog/recently_products/viewed_count';

/**
 * Viewed Product Index model name
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_indexName       = 'reports/product_index_viewed';

/**
 * Retrieve page size (count)
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getPageSize()
{
    if ($this->hasData('page_size')) {
        return $this->getData('page_size');
    }
    return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_RECENTLY_VIEWED_COUNT);
}

/**
 * Added predefined ids support
 */
public function getCount()
{
    $ids = $this->getProductIds();
    if (!empty($ids)) {
        return count($ids);
    }
    return parent::getCount();
}

/**
 * Prepare to html
 * check has viewed products
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getCount()) {
        return '';
    }
    $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
}
```

if it will not work for guests - try to change last function in php file to

```
   protected function _toHtml()
{
 /*   if ($this->_hasViewedProductsBefore() === false) {
        return '';
    } */

    $this->setDisplayMinimalPrice('1');
    $collection = $this->_getRecentProductsCollection();

    $hasProducts = (bool)count($collection);
//        if (is_null($this->_hasViewedProductsBefore())) {
//           Mage::getSingleton('reports/session')->setData('viewed_products', $hasProducts);
//        }
    if ($hasProducts) {
        $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($collection);
    }

    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind response it's help me but it will not display recently view products once i close my browser and get back again is there any option for that!

Comment: these products are saved in session, so maybe just session become expired

Comment: yes i did it and it's work but i want to show recently view product to the guest user same as the registered user! Did you observed that the when Registered user close their browser and comes back at that time it will show the recently product which he visited last time! so i want same for the guest user so once they close browser and comes back in my site again he will get his last recently viewed products. now i think you get an idea

Comment: I got an idea from the beginning. but on this site http://www.buyarearugs.com/recently-viewed-items/  this works for guests by default.  so probably your issue is based on session lifetime. I don't see any other reason, sorry.

Comment: it's ok my friend but your solution is work for me i set recently view product for guest user in cookies so it will display recently view product to them. thnx for your kind response

Answer (score 2):

Block Recently Viewed Products works fine without any code modification in magento 1.6-1.9.2.2
If block is not shown you need check:

1. Block is properly added to page in visible container (by default block added to right sidebar)
2. Log is Enabled. Check System->Configuration->System->Log Option "Enable Log" = Yes
3. Rebuild index "Category Product" (catalog_category_product)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know - it should work fine for guests. at least it works on my site
here is how I put that on a page:

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.recently.viewed" template="reports/recently_viewed.phtml" />
```

Comment: Hello my friend i think recenlty_viewed.phtml file is not there in magento 1702 will you please copy/paste your recently_viewed.phtml file here so that i can get an idea how you set in your site.