# Magento Recently Viewed Products for non logged users

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using default magento 1.9.x Recently Viewed Products block on a CMS page

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

But default magento Recently Viewed Products block only support for logged in users, so it only show when i logged in

I checked the file

```
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Abstract.php
```

and It's **line number 138** function set a customer id for product collection for filter the results.

But i think normal site visitors not have that kind of id.

```
if ($this->getCustomerId()) { 
                       $this->_collection->setCustomerId($this->getCustomerId());
 }
```

Anyone know how to get recently viewed products by setting an id to above or by using another way.

i also tried this answer but it didn't work at all

[How to get Recently View Product For Guest User In Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682483/how-to-get-recently-view-product-for-guest-user-in-magento)

Comment: Can you tell me after try that code, which error you are facing?

Comment: not getting any error, just nothing happens when i change that codes inside "protected function _toHtml()" function according to answer

Comment: Have you debug the code, what that function return?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Go to Admin ->CMS->Pages->AnyCmsPage

Step 2 : Go to-> AnyCmsPage-> Design

Step 3 :Copy and Pase the following code in Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">
    <action method="addPriceBlockType">
        <type>bundle</type>
        <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
        <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
    </action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: It works fine if the user logged in to site, but if not this not shows products